# How to echo "$@" so the result is valid bash and maintains proper quoting?

Tags: bash

What do I put in `wrapper.sh`, if I want this:

```
wrapper.sh "hello world" arg2 '' "this ' thing"
```

to output:

```
Now please run:
other-command "hello world" arg2 '' "this ' thing"
```

I realize and am fine with that the original quotation is lost and the output perhaps will be quoted differently, as long as `other-command` gets the correct parameters when the command is cut'n'pasted to the shell.

I'm aware of `"$@"` which works well for *calling* other programs, but not for echoing valid bash to `STDOUT` as far as I can tell.

This looks pretty nice but requires Perl *and* `String::ShellQuote` (which I'd like to avoid):

```
$ perl -MString::ShellQuote -E 'say shell_quote @ARGV' other-command "hello world" arg2 '' "this ' thing"
other-command 'hello world' arg2 '' 'this '\'' thing'
```

This doesn't work - notice how the zero-length arg is missing:

```
$ perl -E 'say join(" ", map { quotemeta $_ } @ARGV)' other-command "hello world" arg2 '' "this ' thing"
other\-command hello\ world arg2  this\ \'\ thing
```

again, I'd like to avoid using Perl or Python...

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `@Q` parameter transformation.

```
$ set -- "hello world" arg2 '' 'this " thing'
$ echo other-command "${@@Q}"
other-command 'hello world' 'arg2' '' 'this " thing'
```

Comment: This tends to look nicer than `printf %q`, which only uses backslashes, no quotes. For whatever reason they quote things differently.

Answer (score 6):

If you intend the output to be re-`eval`ulated, then you need to `printf "%q"`. You script could look like:

```
echo Now please run:
echo "other-command$(printf " %q" "$@")"
```